# Use one-element STL container as cache?

Tags: c++

I have a class (let's call it `Class1`), where the objects of this class occasionally need an object of another class (let's call it `Class2`). Objects of `Class2` are expensive to construct, so I want to construct it only if really needed, and then save it as cache for future use in the respective object of `Class1`.

One possibility would be to have a `Class2*` (or smart pointer) data member in `Class1` which initially is the `nullptr`, but this creates the usual difficulties with memory management, copying objects of `Class1` etc. Of course this is a manageable problem, but I want to prevent this if possible.

Why not use a STL container data member for Class1 like `std::vector` or `std::unordered_map` which are empty at the beginning and, if needed, the object of `Class2` is saved (by constructing it with an `emplace`-like member function) as the only element in the container?
I assume this has worse performance, but probably it's not that bad comparing to the resources needed to construct a `Class2` object...

*So, my question distilled*:
Is it a good idea to use a one-element container as a data member for caching?
If not, why not and what is a good alternative?
If yes, which container would be best to use?

Thanks four your help and opinions!

**Edit:** To clarify what should happen if an object of `Class1` is copied: Either the cached object should be copied into the new object, or the new cache should be empty, both is fine. What I don't want is to copy a pointer to the same object.

**Edit 2:** I should have mentioned already at the beginning that the code uses only C++11 features up to now and it would be good if it stayed like this. But I also appreciate all the comments mentioning C++14 and C++17 features since they are interesting and useful in general.

Comment: "(or smart pointer)" is your answer. In particular, `std::unique_ptr` sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: I think [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is the way to go if you can use C++17.

Comment: Does a copied `Class1` object need the cached `Class2` object to be copied at the time of the copy, or do you want the `Class1` copy to start out with nothing in the `Class2` cache? In other words, does a copied `Class1` need to maintain the `Class2` state, or will a newly created `Class2` object work?

Comment: @Pete Becker: The problem with the `std::unique_ptr` is that I want the cached object to be copied if I copy an object of `Class1`, exactly how it would be with an STL container. `std::unique_ptr` does not have a copy constructor for such things...

Comment: (Great minds think alike!)  The other important question here is whether these two classes (independently) need heap allocation (including “I don’t care”).

Comment: To answer the copy-question: If an object of `Class1` is copied I want that the cached `Class2` object is copied as well (or it can also be empty at the beginning, both is fine). What I do not want is that something like a pointer is copied. There should be a new cached object.

Comment: @r3musn0x: Looks cool! But the code is C++11 at the moment I don't want to use C++17 features just for this one thing...

Comment: @DavisHerring: I would say "I don't case"... ;)

Comment: I clarified the copy-question as an edit of the main post.

Comment: @tz39R, the benefit of using `std::optional` is that it doesn't require any heap allocation unlike all other options. I guess if you can't or don't want to use C++17 for this one thing you will probably end up inventing it yourself anyway :)

Comment: @r3musn0x Indeed, I was thinking about that... ;)  But then I have to implement `emplace`-like functions etc myself which I wanted to prevent... ;)

Comment: @tz39R I don't see why that is a problem. You can copy the pointee just fine, like normal. Just do a `make_unique` in `Class1`'s copy constructor!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: `make_unique` is C++14, although it’s of course just a convenience.

Comment: @DavisHerring True!

Comment: Given a restriction to C++11, I think I like the idea of using a container to wrap the lazily constructed object.  All the detalis for copying and RAII are handled automatically.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, this is what I was thinking... Any idea which container would be best for this purpose? I know that `std::vector` already claims and array with many elements when initialized, so maybe some kind of map might be more suitable? I don't know how memory is managed there exactly...

Comment: @tz39R: I'd think `vector` would be the least resource intensive (but since the usage would be so limited, I don't think that there's really much difference). While not mandated by the standard, the default constructor for `std::vector` shouldn't allocate.  If just before you actually construct the `Class2` object you `reserve(1)` I'd expect an optimal memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't typically use a container for this; though there's nothing wrong with a container only having one element, we generally use them because we want to manage a collection of more than one element, and their design revolves around that functionality.

---

Traditionally, then, not to gain performance so much as to signal intent, you'd want some kind of "optional" object, and in the olden days you'd implement that by `new`-ing an instance of your type only when you need it (and keeping a null pointer otherwise). Since C++11 you should use `std::unique_ptr` for that purpose instead, solving your *"usual difficulties with memory management"*.

If you want copying your class to deep-copy the cache, simply put `m_cache(other.m_cache ? std::make_unique<TheType>(*other.m_cache) : nullptr)` in your copy constructor's init list!

---

In modern times (since C++17, and even before if you're happy with Boost), you can skip the dynamic allocation (and deep copy antics) and **use `std::optional` for this instead**, which is the current idiomatic solution.

You could always have implemented this with placement-`new` and a `bool`, actually, but it's nice to have a pre-packaged solution to do all that for us.

Note that, as a consequence of the non-dynamic allocation, this solution will *always* take up `sizeof(TheType)+sizeof(bool)` space, whether your cache is in use or not.

Comment: Note, however, that `std::optional` does not allocate from the free store, so it will occupy at least as much space as the type of the object being managed even if there is no contained object.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair I suppose that's worth mentioning; have edited; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `optional` type.

[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) in C++17.

Before you might use [`boost::optional`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or other libraries implementing it.

Or implement your own version.

Comment: I agree, `std::optional` is basically what I want. Since I want to restrict the code to C++11 compatible solutions I am thinking about implementing my own version.  
But still: What exactly is wrong with the one-element container idea (apart from the fact that intention might not be clear from commented code)? For them I can assume that everything is thought of regarding copying, memory management etc.

Comment: If you want to implement your own optional (and you want anyway wrap your logic in another class than `Class1`), quickly, you might indeed use `std::vector` with caveats you know.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of `std::optional` from C++17 (or a workalike like `boost::optional`), you can certainly use a container or a `std::unique_ptr` (with an extra heap allocation in either case).  The latter case requires wrapping to be copyable, but **wrapping** is a good idea anyway to avoid misuse and introduce (part of) the standard interface you’ll use later:

```
template<class T>
struct coptional {  // container-based
  template<class ...AA> T& emplace(AA &&...aa) {
    reset();
    c.emplace_back(std::forward<AA>(aa)...);
    return **this;
  }
  void reset() noexcept {c.clear();}
  explicit operator bool() noexcept {return !c.empty();}
  T& operator*() {return c.front();}
  const T& operator*() const {return c.front();}
private:
  std::vector<T> c;
};

template<class T>
struct uoptional {  // unique_ptr-based
  uoptional() {}
  uoptional(const uoptional &u)
#ifndef EMPTY_COPY
    noexcept : p(u ? new T(*u) : nullptr)
#endif
    {}
  uoptional(uoptional &&u)=default;
  uoptional& operator=(const uoptional &u)
#ifdef EMPTY_COPY
    noexcept
#endif
  {
    if(this!=&u)
#ifdef EMPTY_COPY
      reset();  // don’t use old cache with new value
#else
      p.swap(uoptional(u).p);
#endif
    return *this;
  }
  uoptional& operator=(uoptional&&)=default;

  template<class ...AA> T& emplace(AA &&...aa) {
    // make_unique requires C++14:
    p.reset(new T(std::forward<AA>(aa)...));
    return **this;
  }
  void reset() noexcept {p.reset();}
  explicit operator bool() noexcept {return p;}
  T& operator*() {return *p;}
  const T& operator*() const {return *p;}
private:
  std::unique_ptr<T> c;
};
```

The `unique_ptr` version requires the special member functions to be defined, but this comes with a bonus of easily supporting the **empty-copy** case as illustrated.  It can also not propagate `const` if that’s valuable (as it might be for a cache).

Comment: Code's pretty dense; could use some documenting comments

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I documented the hard parts of the implementation already—the *interface* is [already documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: That's `std::optional`. This is `coptional<T>` and `uoptional<T>`. I have no idea what those names mean, and that's because you did not tell me. If the three share the same interface, and are intended to be used in exactly the same way, you should say & document that... as well as the differences between them and when each should/should not be used.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I added comments that explain the naming (which I hope is no surprise).  The rest of what you mentioned is already addressed in the prose; I don’t see the purpose in incorporating it as code comments.

Comment: It would make it (much) better code. Okay, we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I’m not trying to write “good code”—I’m trying to *show* how one solves this particular problem, with a minimum of flair.  Making the code look perfect (*e.g.*, with extensive Doxygen interface descriptions, unit tests, and a design specification) would *detract* from that goal by obscuring the connection between the container/`unique_ptr` and the problem statement.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you add things that make it worse (why would I do that? who said anything about unit tests or design specifications? don't be sarcastic), I was suggesting that you add the amount of documentation that makes the code easy to understand and to use, without being a hindrance. At the moment, as I said, it's very terse, and unlikely to be of much help to the OP. Remember: you're teaching.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: OK, I’ll bite: *where* do you think such documentation is needed?  It’s not obvious to me what it needs (other than generic “polish”, which is what what I was describing, not sarcastically).  I (quite seriously) recognize this as a problem—not knowing what needs comments—so please teach *me*!

Comment: In that case we're venturing outside of the scope of a comments thread and I encourage you to ask a question on Software Engineering about this :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: You plainly thought some part of it was significantly lacking.  Can you identify just one such improvement or a place that needs it?  Improving StackOverflow answers is necessarily on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: But more broadly teaching you how to use comments in your code is off-topic for this thread

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used `std::vector` as a container and not one of the other options (e.g. `std::map` with an integer key)?

Comment: @tz39R: It’s a good default in general and has obvious, low overhead with no comparisons needed to find the one element.